# External jquery is not working at load time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in one task in that I want to create online visiting card in html. Now, at load times it looks like this in which I have draw the different shaped.

[image]

As per you see the first image I have draw the different shaped

[image]

In this second image when I am selecting a picture at that time shaped toolkit was hide and so from that I unable to create a shaped over an image.

So as per I research in my code I realized that jquery "initialize: function()" is not load after the selecting picture. So it can be said that at load time jquery is not excuting.

Here is my code,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/kinetic-v3.9.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/version1.js"></script>
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- Menu -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery.1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/jquery.min.1.9.0.js"></script>
    <!-- backbone -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/underscore.min.1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/backbone.min.0.9.10.js"></script>

    <!-- wColorPicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Pixanova_files/wColorPicker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/wColorPicker.js"></script>

    <!-- wPaint -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Pixanova_files/wPaint.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/wPaint.js"></script>

    <!-- pixanova -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Pixanova_files/pixanova.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Pixanova_files/pixanova.css">


    <div id="wrapper">
      <!--header-->

      <div id="content">

        <!-- container is the div id from where the image is display -->

        <div id="container" style="width:600px; height:600px; float:right"> </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pixanova = new PixanovaView321();
        </script>

        <div id="editor">
          <ul id="text" style="float: left; margin-right:10px;">
            <!--<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;margin-left:80px;margin-bottom:20px;"> Image Uploading<img src="images/ajax.png" alt="loading"> 
            </div>-->
            <div id="container2" style="width:140px;"> </div>

            <li>
              <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <input type="submit" id="textsubmit" value="Add Text"/>

            <select name="Choice" onchange="setImage(this);">
                <option value="images/blue.jpg">Photo 1</option>
                <option value="images/black.jpg">Photo 2</option>
                <option value="images/red.jpg">Photo 3</option>
                <option value="images/redplan.jpg">Photo 4</option>
            </select> 

            <input type='file' />

            </li>
          </ul>
          <p class="clearing" /></p>
                  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--container--> 

    </body>
```

here the external pixanova.js code from where the toolkit has calling

//This variable is calling the PixanovaView321 function in pixanova.html

```
var PixanovaView321 = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    initialize: function()
    {
        alert();
        //Menu option
        $('#container').wPaint({
            menuOffsetX: 50,
            menuOffsetY: 50,
            menuOrientation: 'horizontal',
            strokeStyle: "yellow"
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: jquery does not appear to be included in your page.

Comment: I have included...

Comment: where? edit the question if you've made a change to the code. And check your browser console for errors, and report any errors here.

Comment: I am not getting any type of the error. My problem is that when I upload the image by select the dropdown item at that time shaped toolbox has been hide. So, I don't want to hide that toolbox.

Comment: you mentioned that the initialise method wasn't firing. I saw that you appeared not to have jquery in your code and that the initialise method required jquery (assuming that $ maps to jQuery in your code). If you've included jquery now then any jquery-related syntax error will have gone. I just wanted to check there were no others. I don't know anything about the pixanova tool sadly, so can't help you with the toolbox issue. Have you read all the documentation to see if a method exists to summon a toolbox?

Comment: yes. I read. And now I have declared the whole external js file which I am using in this task.

Comment: check your JS os jQuery code to find where the element is being hidden and comment the code, run again and check, maybe initialize is not being run because the element exist...

Comment: No it not like this. there is no problem of js file. All are working fine. the problem is that after load the jquery  initialize: function() is not working but it is working before the load.

Comment: now I can see you have got jquery declared **three** times! Remove the duplicates, it could easily cause an issue. Only one copy of jquery should be present on the page at any one time.